# for my current theme( own custom ) the default menu options are disabled in wp-admin?

Tags: themes

for my current theme( own custom ) the default menu options are disabled in wp-admin, please help me to enable it. The following image shows the problem.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can use custom menu's, you have to add one. Try adding the menu by typing a name and clicking save. If you don't have custom menu's in the theme files, you should still be able to use the custom menu widget assuming you have enabled them in your functions.php file. If you don't have either, just comment here and I'll explain how to add them.

Comment: dear Jeremy Jared, thanks for your answer. I've created a menu names **Test**, then called the same with the code as `wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Test' ) );`, it is working fine. am I right on this ?

Comment: what is the use of `register_nav_menu()` here, I couldn't understand from [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu). could you please help me ?

Comment: The question about `register_nav_menu()` should be it's own quetstion, not a comment. `register_nav_menu()` Allows you to populate the theme locations box and makes it possible to interchange menus much much more easily.